# LaTeX, MiKTeX, using variables

Tags: latex, miktex

I'm still pretty new to TeX and MiKTex but I had a question. I want to be able to access a variable called VERSION that would store the current version number of my document and use that in my TeX document instead of having to hardcode the number each time. Also, I use the TeXworks application in MiKTeX to generate my PDF versions of the documents. Is there a way, using TeXworks to have it also recognize this variable when generating the PDF?

Thanks for any help!

Russ

Comment: Where does the version number come from? Is it from some version control system like git or do you want to manually set it in your document?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I want to be able to manually set it, but then have this VERSION variable in my LaTeX document, then reflect what I have set the version number to be. Does that make sense?

Comment: Where do you want the version variable? Inside your document? Somewhere else?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, for example, the header should have the document title and the version. Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the version number in a macro and reuse it throughout the document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\version}{1.3}

\title{test \version}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

The current version \version\ is stable

\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks good. Is there a way to pass the value from the command line or enter that somewhere and have TeX Workshop find it?

Comment: @RussUrquhart you can compile your document with `pdflatex \def\version{1.3}\input{filename.tex}` to pass the version number from the command line to the document instead of defining it inside the document. That's why I kept asking where the version number comes from.